# React router dom LINK concatunates

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-link

I'm trying to create navigation between some categories while changing the link on click
I need to get this `localhost/blog/category/:category1` it works for the first category selected but when I click again I get this `localhost/blog/category/blog/category/:category2`.

I'm using LINK for redirection

```
<Link
  className="nav-link"
  aria-current="page"
  to={`blog/category/${item}`}
>
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
<Link
  className="nav-link"
  aria-current="page"
  to={`/blog/category/${item}`}
>
```